# Replacing Node.js require statements with import/export statements from AWS Lambda layers

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, import, aws-lambda

I am trying to use [import](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_statements) statements instead of require statements in my AWS Lambda project.

I need to import functionalities from the AWS SDK (which should be plausible when using the v3, as stated on the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-sqs/index.html)).

To do so, I uploaded the dependency (@aws-sdk/client-sqs) as a Lambda layer, with the following tree structure:

```
.
└── nodejs
    ├── node_modules
    │   ├── @aws-crypto
    │   ├── @aws-sdk
    │   ├── bowser
    │   ├── entities
    │   ├── fast-xml-parser
    │   ├── tslib
    │   └── uuid
    ├── package-lock.json
    └── package.json
```

Back in the Lambda function, the following code (index.js) runs with no issues:

```
const { SQSClient, AddPermissionCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sqs");

const handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

module.exports = {
    handler,
}
```

But, as I stated in the beginning, I want to instead use import/export statements, so I replaced it with the following code:

```
import { SQSClient, AddPermissionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

const handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
    };
    return response;
};

export {
    handler,
}
```

I also created a package.json with the `"type": "module"` entry, located on the same folder as index.js:

```
{
  "name": "test_es6",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module"
}
```

However, when testing the function it fails, with the following error message:

> "Cannot find package '@aws-sdk/client-sqs' imported from /var/task/index.js
> Did you mean to import @aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-cjs/index.js?"

I tried changing the import line to:
`import { SQSClient, AddPermissionCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs/dist-cjs/index.js";`
but it had no effect, resulting in the same error.

So, I guess I must be doing something wrong? Has anyone faced this issue when using AWS Lambda Layers? Thanks!